# Terraria Truffle Problems

Tags: ios, terraria-mobile

I often surf the terraria wiki to look for more interesting things to do or make. So when I found out about the truffle it (the last NPC I need) it sounded like a great thing to get. The truffle had been moaning at me for AGES now (named muscaria) even though I didn't know of its existence. Now I have made a surface mushroom biome and filled all the boxes; but alas, still no joy. [image: Here is his house![][1]]
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the Curse Terraria Wiki, and it says, Even if all the requirements are met the Truffle will sometimes not spawn at all on the mobile version. It it probably just a glitch, but good luck getting the Truffle in the future!